# How to thread two functions where one output effect the others actions

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

Here's my code:

```
import time
import keyboard #pip install keyboard - could use pynput listener instead.
from threading import Thread

hshtag = int(0)
done = False
fire = False


def StopStart(fire):
    while not done:
        global fire
        if keyboard.is_pressed('#'):
            hshtag = hshtag + 1
            if hshtag % 2 ==0:
                fire = False
            else:
                fire = True
        return fire


def NormalFire():
    while not done:
        global fire
        if fire == True:
            #do x        
        else:
            pass

t1 = Thread(target = StopStart)
t2 = Thread(target = NormalFire(fire))
t1.start()
t2.start()
```

<strike>The problem is function StopStart (should) effect what function Normalfire does but as the function only accepts a value for fire when it starts running (so it doesn't work). What I want is change what function normalfire does with function stopstart. and if you're wondering why I am using threading it because '#do x' actually takes a while to work so as one continuous script if I clicked hash at the wrong time it wouldn't stop. Maybe I could do this with classes instead but im not good with classes so if someone could either help with that or fix the above code that would be great thanks.</strike>

New attempt at explaining what's wrong with the top code - Ok, so both functions should be running simultaneously (which they are) - so no problems there. but as the function StopStart changes the boolean fire to true/false I want that to cause my NormalFire function to change what it is doing - nothing when I haven't clicked hash yet and something if I've clicked hash once but if I then click hash while its running it will finish whats its running then do nothing waiting for hash to be clicked again.

Sorry, my question wasn't clear take this code as a simplification of my core question.

```
##imports
import time
import keyboard #pip install keyboard - could use pynput listener instead.
from threading import Thread

##variable assigning
hshtag = int(0)
done = False
fire = False


def x():
    while not done:
        fire = True
        return fire

def y(fire):
    while not done:
        if fire:
            print('ok')                   
        else:
            pass

t1 = Thread(target = x)
t2 = Thread(target = y(fire))
t1.start()
t2.start()
```

Currently, the above code outputs nothing even though I've set 'fire = true' in function x and returned it how would I edit this code so that when boolean fire changes to true the function y starts printing ok?

Editing like Nair suggested also returns nothing and after 15 second the program stops running edited code:

```
##imports
import time
import keyboard #pip install keyboard - could use pynput listener instead.
from threading import Thread

##variable assigning
hshtag = int(0)
done = False
fire = False


def StopStart():
    while not done:
        fire = True
        return fire

def NormalFire():
    while not done:
        if fire:
            print('ok')                   
        else:
            pass

t1 = Thread(target = StopStart)
t2 = Thread(target = NormalFire)
t1.start()
t2.start()
```

Comment: Can you re-frame your question. Finding hard to understand.

Comment: I've added a simplified piece of code and reframed my question please take another look.

Comment: Your first thread modify the fire flag. However, your second thread use the fire value from script and not from the returned result from first thread. I hope it is clear. One more word of advice, if you expect a result from first thread for second thread to continue using it, then you might also want to wait for first thread to complete before the second one. Hint: Thread Join

Comment: '''##imports
import time
import keyboard #pip install keyboard - could use pynput listener instead.
from threading import Thread

##variable assigning
hshtag = int(0)
done = False
fire = False


def StopStart():
    while not done:
        fire = True
        return fire

def NormalFire():
    while not done:
        if fire:
            print('ok')                   
        else:
            pass

t1 = Thread(target = StopStart)
t2 = Thread(target = NormalFire)
t1.start()
t2.start()'''
 this returns nothing but i have edited it how you have sugested

Comment: a return value of a thread makes no sense nobody reads this value.

I also suggest to add some sleeps in your examples, such, that it is easier to follow the print statements.

in thread2 you could for example add a time.sleep(0.5)

in thread1 there is no need to add a while loop if you abort the task immediately. just simulate it with a sleep e.g. sleep(2) and changing the fire variable.

in order to see the variable in both threads you had to make it  global.

In order to avoid any trouble you had to protect reading / writing that var with a threading.Lock()

Comment: This code is just a simplification to get to the root of my problem with my actual code. your comment about a sleep timer seems odd as a successful test would just spam 'ok' (my code does not). The while loop in function x is there to make it continuos as in my actual code it will be a while loop constantly changing the value of fire. What i want is my function y to respond  to the change in value of fire set in x.

Comment: In your `StopStart` function, before the `while` loop starts, add this line: `global fire`. The way it's written now, any changes you make to `fire` in the loop actually don't affect the object you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to comment so I apologize in advanced. I'm having trouble understanding your question above, but I reworked your code - fix/add whatever you need and get back to me!

```
import time
import keyboard #pip install keyboard - could use pynput listener instead.
from threading import Thread

hshtag = int(0)
done = False
fire = False


def StopStart():
    while not done:
        # global fire - You're setting StopStart up for a param that needs passed, that also is named another variable
        # So it will just over write it (Also, no arg is passed for StopStart(fire))
        if keyboard.is_pressed('#'):
            hshtag = hshtag + 1
            if hshtag % 2 == 0 : fire = False
            else : fire = true
        return fire


def NormalFire():
    while not done:
        #global fire   - Don't need to global it, you would've had to global done if that was the case
        if fire: # don't need == true, just need if fire (if true)
            print("x")       

t1 = Thread(target=StopStart)
t2 = Thread(target=NormalFire)
t1.start()
t2.start()
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to reword what I want to happen when I run the code.

Comment: Ok, so both functions should be running simultaneously (which they are) - so no problems there. but as the function StopStart changes the boolean fire to true/false i want that to cause my NormalFire function to change what it is doing - nothing when I haven't clicked hash yet and something if i've clicked hash once but if i then click hash while its running it will stop.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that this is exactly what you're asking for. I would maybe listen for keyboard events outside of either thread. Instead, just bind keyboard events to a callback which set a `threading.Event` object. Sorry for the weird and slightly morbid example:

```
from pynput import keyboard
from threading import Thread, Event

plate_dropped = Event()

def on_press(key):
    if key is keyboard.Key.enter:
        plate_dropped.set()

listener = keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press)

def poll_plate_status():
    from time import sleep
    from random import choice
    messages = [
        "It sure is tempting, eh?",
        "Are you gonna do it?"
    ]
    print("It'd be a shame if someone would drop this plate and scare grandpa!")
    while not plate_dropped.is_set():
        print(choice(messages))  
        sleep(0.5)
    print("The plate has been dropped!")

def poll_grandpa_status():
    from time import sleep
    from random import choice
    messages = [
        "*zzzZZZzzz*",
        "*Snoooreee*"
    ]
    print("Grandpa is sound asleep.")
    while not plate_dropped.is_set():
        print(choice(messages))
        sleep(0.5)
    print("HUH!?")


plate_thread = Thread(target=poll_plate_status, daemon=True)
grandpa_thread = Thread(target=poll_grandpa_status, daemon=True)

plate_thread.start()

grandpa_thread.start()

listener.start()
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm struggling to understand whether this achieves the same thing I was aiming to do with my code I've added a simplified example of what I want to do I would really appreciate it if you took a look.

Answer (score 0):

```
##imports
import time
import keyboard #pip install keyboard - could use pynput listener instead.
from threading import Thread

##variable assigning
hshtag = int(0)
done = False
fire = False


def StopStart(self, interval=1):
    hshtag = 0
    self.interval = interval
    while not done:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('#'):
            hshtag = hshtag + 1
            if hshtag % 2 ==0:
                fire = False
            else:
                fire = True

def NormalFire():
    while not done:
        print('NormalFire Runs')
        time.sleep(1)
        if fire:
            print('*fires*')                   
        else:
            print('*does nothing*')

#t1 = Thread(target = StopStart, daemon=True)
t2 = Thread(target = NormalFire, daemon=True)
#t1.start()
t2.start()
while not done:
    #time.sleep()
    if keyboard.is_pressed('#'):
        hshtag = hshtag + 1
        time.sleep(0.1)
        if hshtag % 2 ==0:
            fire = False
            print(fire)
        else:
            fire = True
            print(fire)
```

I realised my problem was my ides of threading (im new to it) this achieves what I wanted thanks for all the help.